# Error installing node and npm

Tags: node.js

After downloading node.js on my Mac, I want to install npm.

when I run this command:

```
sudo npm install node-dev -g
```

I am getting this error:

> npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys /usr/local/bin/node-dev -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/bin/node-dev node-dev@2.6.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev ├── filewatcher@1.1.2 ├── resolve@1.1.6 ├── dynamic-dedupe@0.2.0 (xtend@2.0.6) ├── dateformat@1.0.11 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0) └── node-notifier@4.2.1 (shellwords@0.1.0, clone@0.1.19, growly@1.2.0, minimist@1.1.1, semver@4.3.6, which@1.1.1, cli-usage@0.1.1)

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [this Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing a good question. The more effect that you put forth, the more likely you are to get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning that the `object-keys` library version is deprecated and that you should update it.  It's not an error and shouldn't prevent installation of anything else. It seems like one of the libraries that `node-dev` is using uses this version of `object-keys` [(`node-dev` itself does not seem to need it)](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev/blob/master/package.json).

The `dynamic-dedup` library is relying on an older version of `xtend` [which uses this old version of object-keys](https://github.com/Raynos/xtend/blob/8152ab7a4ac9721eda47314518885b67a555fde1/package.json)

I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/thlorenz/dynamic-dedupe/issues/2) for this library, but beyond this there is not much you can do other than maintaining your own version of the library locally which is *probably* not the best idea.

At any rate, I don't think there will be any noticeable impact from this warning.

---

As an aside, I recommend that you [*do not* use `sudo` with `npm install`](https://blog.explosion-pills.com/dont-use-sudo-with-npm/) (disclaimer: this is my own blog).

Comment: @KartikeyaGupta `sudo` has nothing to do with it.  Please read the top part of my answer before the horizontal rule.